# Как создать функцию с таблицей в качестве входного параметра?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle19c

Как создать функцию с таблицей (Х) в качестве входного параметра, чтобы таблица Х могла использоваться внутри функции для соединения с другой таблицей Y?

Таблица X может содержать тысячи записей.

Мне известно, что можно передать парамретром имя таблицы в символьном виде, а затем использовать динамический SQL, но этот вариант не подходит.

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Writing Oracle stored procedure with Oracle table as Input parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64139587) от участника [@Vikash Kumar Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2801986/vikash-kumar-sharma)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/64139587

Answer (score 2):

Начиная с веерсии 19.6 можно создать SQL макрос. При этом, функция примет таблицу как параметер и вернёт запрос, который будет сразу выолнен. Во время парсинга БД выполнит замену актуального параметра таблицы на переданную таблицу.

Простой воспроизводимый пример (на [Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/ln3e2afo92wxirfkb7h2uk76j)):

```
create or replace function f (tab dbms_tf.table_t) return varchar2 sql_macro as
begin
    return 'select * from tab 
    join ( select level rn from dual connect by level <= 2 ) on c1 = rn';
end f;
/
create table t1 (c1 int);
create table t2 (c1 int);

insert into t1 values (1);
insert into t2 values (2);

select * from f (t1);

   C1    RN
----- ----- 
    1     1 

select * from f ( t2 );

   C1    RN
----- -----
    2     2
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64142630) от участника [@Chris Saxon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1485955/chris-saxon)</sub>